# Angular JS Form Validation

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, validation

I'm working on an admin where users can add X amount of cells.  Each cell consists of:

- name
- imageURL
- destination link

User can bulk add cells (starts with 8, they could add 20 at once) or one at a time.

I need to validate each field to confirm that they are good.  I had planned on using angular form validation for this.  Unfortunately there is the requirement which states that should the user have X # of items, but only filled in half (leaves any entire cell empty) just disregard that cell as a whole.

The problem lies in that  if there are 10 cells on load, the form (holds all the cells) is pristine / invalid. I fill in all 10 items, form is now dirty / valid.  I add 5 more, form is dirty / invalid.  fill out 2 of those cells and want to submit, form is still dirty / invalid when I would want it to be dirty / valid

Any thoughts on this?

Example plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/qwObH5LnxLvgJydJlJVS?p=preview

Bonus points on if I can do this without having to use a form tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want empty rows to be valid, but empty input fields in a non-empty row to be invalid.

To achieve this, you can add conditional requirements to each field using `ng-required`, so that it is only required if there is at least some text elsewhere in the row.

From your plunkr, you can replace `required` with `ng-required` on each input:

```
<li ng-repeat="cell in cells">
    <input type="text" name="dest" ng-model="cell.dest" placeholder="Destination Link" ng-required="cell.src || cell.name"/>
    <input type="text" name="src" ng-model="cell.src" placeholder="Image Link" ng-required="cell.dest || cell.name"/>
    <input type="text" name="cellName" ng-model="cell.name" placeholder="Name" ng-required="cell.src || cell.dest"/>
</li>
```

To improve scalability, you could also define a method on the cell objects or the controller to evaluate whether a cell object is blank:

```
function cellCtrl($scope) {
    ...
    $scope.isBlankCell = function(cell) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and call that method from the template:

```
<li ng-repeat="cell in cells">
    <input type="text" name="dest" ng-model="cell.dest" placeholder="Destination Link" ng-required="isBlankCell(cell)"/>
    <input type="text" name="src" ng-model="cell.src" placeholder="Image Link" ng-required="isBlankCell(cell)"/>
    <input type="text" name="cellName" ng-model="cell.name" placeholder="Name" ng-required="isBlankCell(cell)"/>
</li>
```

Comment: This worked spot on, thank you for your help.  You've restored faith in Internet Humanity.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your example on plunkr.

Adding a delete button, the user can delete the rows that do not want to fill. So the form comes back to the dirty/valid state.

Comment: Although I appreciate the comment, that's not the question.  There are X buttons, but this is a matter of user experience.  Customers might not be the smartest, but we should make their life easier.